# How to launch already installed app from iPhone using appium

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am writing an automation script using Java + TestNG + Appium.

In a test scenario, I am trying to launch already installed application on iphone. (Box in this case). Box contains some MS office file which I need to access. 
I am not very sure how can I achieve this.

I tried multiple options such as extracting .app file from iTunes and deploying using Appium, but no success.

Can someone please guide me, if this is possible. If yes, how?

Comment: please show your path that you have to tried.

Comment: I installed Box app from iTunes. Navigated to "/Users/admin/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications" location. Extracted spa file from application. Used the same.

Comment: The intention here is just to launch the Box app installed on iPhone. I need to open MS office files from Box app. If launching the third party app is not possible, is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: You can pass in the bundleId and it will find the application if it is already installed on the iPhone. You do not need to have the .app or .ipa file if the app is already installed on the device.

Comment: Can you please paste a code snippet. Since, i came across this solution, but dint exactly get, how to implement. I have bundle id for Box app.

Comment: do you to installed the application from itunes???

Comment: Yes. Box is installed from iTunes.

Comment: if you are installed live app this is not possible please see my answer....

Comment: Thanks for your response Amit. Just wanted to know, isn't there any alternate way to achieve this. Just like app package and app activity does on Android platform. OR something like locating the elements using Xpath on home screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automate a preinstalled app with following scenario.

1.This will only work for applications that are signed with a DEVELOPMENT cert.

2.This will NOT work for applications that are signed with a DISTRIBUTION cert

3.If you have created the app with a developer provisioning profile, and built yourself. Or downloaded it using testFlight, and is signed with a development provisioning profile

4.This is because Apple's Instruments will not allow you to interact with those applications which is live. (Even if you knew the bundleId)

if your app is in development mode please follow these things
1.The bundleId of the app that was installed on the device. Use that as the app capability.

2. Follow the Appium [Real Devices](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/appium-setup/real-devices.md) guide (substitute any `.ipa`/`.app` reference with the bundleId)

In addition to your regular `desiredCapabilities` (ex. `platformName`, `platformVersion`, `deviceName`).. these should be your `desiredCapabilities`:

**For preinstalled apps**

```
desiredCaps['app'] = 'yourbindleID'
```

**Device's unique identifier**

```
desiredCaps['udid'] = '1824y983h2849gh2498'
```

Comment: I achieved this using Xpath. By sending `HOME` screen event using apple script and accessing other apps by their Xpath.

Comment: Hi @Amit  

I am trying to open app through appium. I am getting "Failed to create WDA session".

What i did? :

Installed paytm.app from itunes.
I wrote all capabilities, bundle id and app location of paytm
opened webdriver with xcode and signed in.
running code with appium. It is able to install the app but it is unable to launch.(It is opening and closing in seconds).          Please help me

Comment: Hi @VKS, Its little unclear what have you tried. How did you manage to get PayTM .App file. Also, "PayTM opened webdriver with xcode and signed in" . I didn't quite catch this part. The issue which you are observing could be because of mismatch of Xcode version which signs the app and version of appium your are using. Can you check once?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
HashmMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String,Object>();
args.put("bundleId","*YOUR_APP_BUNDLEID*");
driver.executeScript("mobile: launchApp", args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code snippet:

cap.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.APP_NAME, "{appName}");

This capability is the MOST important capability to open the app automatically if the app is already installed on mobile device.

```
    public static IOSDriver<IOSElement> capabilities() throws IOException {
    
    //Configure absolute path of the .ipa file

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//automation.properties");
    System.out.println(fis);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(fis);     

    File f = new File("src/test/resources");
    File fs = new File(f, (String)prop.get("iOSAppName"));
    
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, (String)prop.get("iOSPlatformName"));
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, (String)prop.get("iDeviceUDID"));
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");

    driveriOS = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), cap);
    
    //Check app is already installed if NOT install app to device automatically
    if(driveriOS.isAppInstalled("com.test.app")==false)
    {
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    
    //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, (String)prop.get("iOSBrowserType"));
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, (String)prop.get("iOSPlatformVersion"));
    cap.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.APP_NAME, "{appName}"); //Provide your app name here
    cap.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID, (String)prop.get("updateWDABundleId"));
    cap.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    cap.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", (String)prop.get("xcodeOrgId"));

    driveriOS = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), cap);
    driveriOS.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    stepRecorder(Status.INFO, "iOS Driver initiated");

    return driveriOS; 

}
```